Where can the OP show the results of following an accepted answer given by another user?
https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/299097/what-is-the-best-way-to-terminate-wires-formerly-connected-to-a-240v-in-wall-hea#:~:text=ceiling%20with%20cracks%3F-,%2B10,to%20terminate%20wires%20formerly%20connected%20to%20a%20240V%20in%2Dwall%20heater%3F,-%2B8
In the above question, the OP updated the question at the end to show results from following and accepted answer from another user. This edit was deleted by another user and the comment stated that it should have been added as an answer, not as an update to the question. I have seen many instances where updates were made to the question to explain what was done when following an accepted answer. I am aware that if the OP actually answers their own question, it's an answer but following someone else's answer isn't.

Pretty clear this is a logistical flaw in either moderation or more probable the SE abilities.     If OP answers after accepting following advice of answer... that is a duplicate answer.    If OP conveys something wrong, does something wrong or veers off in their answer, it is a bad answer.    If they comment it quite likely is deleted over time.    I create CMSs to compete with SE - I completely understand where SE code/logic falls short.

@Triplefault - You are an evil genius.   You answered three times to prove a point.   And the point is because you answered three times I read over the first and when I saw your name again I did not fully read the next two.    Exactly my point that literally no one will read the OPs answer after another is accepted and upvoted.    I guess you could say it helps the person who wrote the answer follow up on it but more times than not the OP didn't follow all of the advices which causes a list of comments and more questions.

Saying that you followed someone else's answer does count as an answer.  Particularly if you are giving a more detailed explanation of how the solution was achieved.
This is normal practice across several SE sites.  The OP should preferably reference the answer they followed and then give details.  I've seen this most often on Vehicle Maintenance but on several others too.  The OP will often accept the answer they followed and post their own answer with photos, linking to the original answer.

Where does the OP give reference; at the end of their question or as a new answer?

@JACK:  In their answer.  The question must remain as just a question.

Perhaps it is worth noting that ANYONE (not just the OP) might follow the advice in an answer (if they had a similar situation). If they want to provide details of how things went, it would certainly be more appropriate in an answer than in the OP's question.

I agree with this but find it objectively flawed as far as how the site is constructed.    If you have accepted an answer with a checkmark then why the hell would I read another answer (often with far less upvotes) that details what was actually done.    Now if you followed the advice of someone but veered off hard at some point, then yes an alternative answer seems OK.    However it seems much more fitting to be part of the question.    The question doesn't disqualify an answer, it just needs to supply a question.   Many questions have multiple follow ups..  to me doing what an answer  (cont)

.... says is just another follow up.    It makes more sense and it is easier to read.    To me the "question" is the question and the story.    The OP having a comprehensive story is what makes a great question.     The fact that the site does not have the mechanism to continue the story after an answer isn't the OP's fault.

@Rob - I get the logic but it makes absolutely no sense for a site like this.    If there are 6-7 answers and one is accepted... I am supposed to read all of them and look at the users and such to figure out who followed whose advice and blah blah blah.    Yea your idea is good in a nice bubble but not practical.   Design flaw of SE.    Not that the question is the best place for the follow up, but it is the only place that will be heard in a logical manner.

The whole entire foundational concept of SE sites is to build a library of question and answer pairs for future readers, not just the OP. How a problem was ultimately solved is clearly an answer and belongs in the answer box. If an OP’s “what I ended up doing” info isn’t going to help anyone else, they can just not post it at all.

@nobody - your statement I completely disagree with.   While you are probably correct if it were "coding" it does not translate to DIY.     95%+ the person supplying a good answer and it is accepted has way more knowledge than the person asking the question.    So when the "OP" in your advice creates another "answer" they may do something wrong, convey something wrong, be unclear, or just veer off from the crux of the original question.   Most answers like this are very poor - some are good.    There should be a "follow up comment" that cannot get deleted, going under answer.

@nobody - further to this... wouldn't this be a duplicate answer?    On half of the non electrical questions I can wait for someone to answer and then answer with the same thing but use a reference story of me doing what an answer said and following the steps.    My answer then would be closed as a duplicate as it should (this site is pretty strict on this).    So you are actually suggesting for them to write an answer that will get closed which is Jack's point of his post.

I put a DV on because I think the way a problem was solved by the OP doesn't answer the question the OP asked. But I just saw the idea to reference the OP's answer in the question, which is a good compromise. Will reverse the DV when SE lets me do so.

I want to mention this and let this simmer in everyone's head.   We are penalizing people for following up when we take the time to answer.
Not only that but if this is considered a "comment" to the answer I have seen many a mod here delete the comment string.    So why would anyone use that method as it isn't intuitive and it can be wiped...
To me logically the OP should follow up in their question with what they did.   If that happens to be following the advice of an answer, it is still part of the original problem which means it belongs in the question.
This site has some serious OCD/WTF issues with a small amount of our senior members and even some mods.    Be nice policy doesn't seem to apply to them.   They can be mean and delete crap and close down questions... but if you call them out on it you are not being "nice".   Closing and deleting when people have taken their time (for free) to help is about as mean as it gets.    The people involved should be ashamed (is that mean?).

Being informed that answers go in the answer box is not a penalty.

Another thought on why OP putting what they did in an answer: It's rather likely no one will read it. The good answer on what OP should do will be up top with all the votes and the checkmark. The OP's "what I did" answer, if posted, will likely come later, when activity on the question has died down, and may not get many votes of its own, so coexisting with the lower-quality and spam answers laying at the bottom of the voting stack.
What the OP did is a valuable part of rounding out the whole question, along with the most helpful answers, and it needs to be seen, if OP wants to post it.
Since SE doesn't have a special "what I did" section within the question/answer paradigm at this time, the best place for "what I did" is in an update at the end of the question. The OP's Actions will be seen easily, not disappeared down below the "my store website has a solution for this problem" spam.

"What I did" really does not answer the question "what should I do"? So "what I did" does not belong in an answer.
I think the OP should put their results from following the answers given in the question as an update. This procedure is seen in many topics on Academia and Workplace SE's.
If the OP posts their own answer on how they followed the other answer(s) it risks being demoted under a lot of other answers, due to not getting upvotes. If the OP takes the checkmark away from the most helpful answer to try to make their result answer more visible it takes away from the helpful answer they followed.
An "Update" section at the bottom of the OP's question is easily understandable.

an example:

?: What gauge wire should I use for this 20 amp circuit?
A: Use 12 gauge.
OP's A: I followed the A above but I used 24 gauge speaker wire.
OP's answer does not answer what they should have done, which is the question they asked.

I agree. That's what we tried to do but like I said, the question edit got rolled back by another user. I rolled it back and the user rolled it again. This probably would have gone on forever so the accepted answer had the update on what the OP did and with pictures.  Hoping a moderator weighs in with an official answer since we've got many opinions here.

“Answer” does not mean “correct answer”. “Use 24 gauge speaker wire” may not be a correct answer but it is certainly an answer (a “not an answer” flag would be declined). If somebody’s “what I did” information isn’t useful or valuable they probably just shouldn’t be sharing it at all - not as an answer, and not in the question.

@nobody Answers that don't answer the question are called out as bad, see example: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/300414/140350 An answer should answer the question. "What I did" does not answer "What should I do?".

A compromise, to handle the concerns of both sides:
OP puts what they did in an answer.
OP updates the question at the bottom with a "See how I solved this" and a link to the OP's answer.
OP's answer won't be buried unnoticed in the spam, because other readers will see the link in the question.
